# How to make a single ion-card item list scrollable

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic4

I've searched around for hours for a way to make a single ion-card scrollable on a page with multiple cards.  It seems the ion-scroll element is deprecated and none of the online tutorials are working.

```js
        <ion-card style="height:150px;" scroll-y="true"  class="groupList">

                <ion-card-header>
                 <!-- some content -->
                </ion-card-header>
                <ion-card-content>
                 <ion-list *ngFor="let group of myGroups">
                    <ion-item>
                        <!-- <ion-avatar slot="start">
                            <img [src]="group.photoUrl"/>    
                        <!-- </ion-avatar>  -->
                        <ion-label>
                            <h2>{{group.groupName}}</h2>
                        </ion-label>
                      </ion-item>
                 </ion-list>
                </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
```

It's just a simple list with a max height...I just want to make the single cards scrollable.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `overflow: scroll` on your groupList class:

In your page.scss file:

```
.groupList {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```